# TYPO3: SQL migration from mininews to news from TYPO3 6.2 LTS to TYPO3 9 LTS

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I'am looking for a migration of very old TYPO3 Extension

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mininews/

to

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/

How are the SQL Statments for this migration?

Answer (score 0):

```
# delete unused or hidden mini news
DELETE FROM tx_mininews_news where deleted = 1 OR hidden = 1;
# Migrate Data
INSERT INTO tx_news_domain_model_news (pid, tstamp, crdate, cruser_id, starttime, endtime,  datetime, title, teaser, bodytext) SELECT pid, tstamp, crdate, cruser_id, starttime, endtime,  datetime, title, teaser, full_text FROM tx_mininews_news;
```